# Getting a custom toolbar to the bottom of the screen for xamarin android

Tags: android, android-xml

I've got a app I'm working on and I have created two custom toolbars.  The top one is correctly at the top of the screen but if you look at the screen shot below I need the bottom black toolbar at the very bottom of the screen....

[image]

and below is my axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/starttoolbar" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SignInView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:background="#d3d3d3"
            android:text=" Sign in below" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BlankView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CustTextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text=" Customer" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/UserName"
            android:text="UserName"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Password"
            android:text="Password"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/LoginButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/GreenButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/Login"
            style="@style/button_text" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottomtoolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbarbottom"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The bottomtoolbar is what I need all the way at the bottom.

And here is the code for the bottomtoolbar Custom Toobar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/HelpButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/RedButton"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back48x58"
        style="@style/back_button_text" />
</Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to this using layout_weight and inserting a space.  So the space had a weight of 1 and the Bottom Title Bar has a weight of 0. Which fixed the problem with the code :

```
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/space2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottomtoolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbarbottom"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
```

[image]